# SQL Azure Default Language

Tags: azure-sql-database

I have created a database with SQL Azure and everything works fine except for date insertion. Our CMS only works with the British English language and I believe the default language is English, not British English.

As far as I can tell there is no way to modify users using the GUI so I have manually created a new user, bound it to the database etc and tried:

```
ALTER LOGIN mylogin WITH DEFAULT_LANGUAGE = British;
```

However I get the error:

> 'Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near 'DEFAULT_LANGUAGE'.

Does anyone know if changing the default language is possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[SQL Azure doesn't support the changing of language](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee336254.aspx), among other options, for your login object.

> SQL Azure Database does not support the following arguments and options when using the ALTER LOGIN statement:
>
> `<set_option>` options:
> DEFAULT_DATABASE
> DEFAULT_LANGUAGE
> CHECK_POLICY
> CHECK_EXPIRATION
> CREDENTIAL
> NO CREDENTIAL

Likely it goes back to the idea and implementation that SQL Azure is a subset of SQL Server, and not a direct analog.

Comment: I thought that would be the case. Thanks for your answer

Comment: @patg : my pleasure. Please remember to vote-up and 'accept' answers on all your StackOverflow questions whenever you find an answer that is helpful.